# How do i deserailize this json string

Tags: deserialize, parsing

Can Any one help me in deserializing this json string:

```
"(ActivityHistory:{AccountId=0011a00000qWdtzAAC, Id=00T1a00001m4m99EAA, WhoId=0031a00000u3iXlAAI, Subject=Call, Status=Completed, Priority=Normal, OwnerId=0051a000001JDEhAAO, IsTask=true}, ActivityHistory:{AccountId=0011a00000qWdtzAAC, Id=00T1a00001lX9SOEA0, ActivityDate=2018-05-10 00:00:00, WhatId=0061a00000OyMbKAAV, WhoId=0031a00000u3iXlAAI, StartDateTime=2018-05-10 00:00:00, Subject=Send Letter, Status=Completed, Priority=Normal, OwnerId=0051a000001JDEhAAO, IsTask=true})"
```

I have tried to use following ways but everytime it thrown an error "Invalid conversion from runtime type.string to map".

```
try{
       Map<String, list<object>> m = (Map<String, list<object>>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonstr);



       system.debug('aa---'+m.get('ActivityHistory'));
       //System.assertEquals('An appliance', m.get('ActivityHistory'));
       }
       catch(exception e){
           system.debug('error--->'+e);

       }

       try{
             Map<String, list<activityhistory>> n = (Map<String, list<activityhistory>>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonstr);
            system.debug('aa---'+n.get('ActivityHistory'));
       }catch(exception e){
           system.debug('error--->'+e);

       }
       try{
            List<object> o =  List<object> JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonstr);
        //   system.debug('aa---'+o.get('ActivityHistory'));
           system.debug('0---'+o);
       }
       catch(exception e){  
            system.debug('error--->'+e);

       }
```

my goal is to extract both the records of activity history, store both the activity history records into a separate string. Then i want to store the individual fields of each record in to another sub-strings.

Comment: The JSON string you have is not a valid JSON structure, please check your JSON for validity before deserializing. You can do it at [JSON Editor](https://jsoneditoronline.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you provide is wrong.
Instead of equals (=), you should put a colon (:) 
Each field must be sorrounded by quotes

For example :

{AccountId=0011a00000qWdtzAAC } ==> { "AccountId" : "0011a00000qWdtzAAC" }

Comment: google json formatter and you'll find a bunch of online tools. here's one that was at the top of google: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ . if you put your json in there you'll see it's invalid. as @ransommule pointed out, you need quotes around properties and (non-numeric/boolean) values and colons to separate them. see https://www.json.org/ for the json spec